# Google Cloud - TLS version

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I install certbot ssl and when I run SSL Labs and I am getting a B on Protocol.  It is telling I am using TLSv1 and TLSv1.1.

I have tried to find through the SSH everywhere there is SSLProtocol, I change it to +TLSv1.2.
`/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf`
`/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf`
`/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf`

SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3  +TLSv1.2

Can someone help me?

Do I need in php.ini files?

Comment: if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could compile apache with the latest version of OpenSSL to enable TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3

For example:

```
SSLProtocol +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
```

to add TLSs1.2  only, you just need to add in your https virtual host configuration:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
```

`-all` is to remove the ssl protocol (SSL 1,2,3 TLS1) and `+TLSv1.2` is adding TLS 1.2

for more compatibility you can use something like:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
```

You can see more information in this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol).

You also could check the following guide on [how to enable or disable SSL and TSL versions](https://support.globalsign.com/ssl/general-ssl/how-enable-or-disable-ssl-and-tls-versions).

Keep in mind that you need to restart your Apache2 to be ready for a test.

And you can test your https website security with an online scanner like [this one](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) or [this other one](https://www.immuniweb.com/ssl/).

**Note: Apache HTTP Server [version 2.4.43](https://httpd.apache.org/#apache-httpd-2446-released-2020-08-07) or newer is required in order to operate a TLS 1.3 web server with OpenSSL 1.1.1.**